# Spring: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, sessionfactory

I am new to spring and keep getting the following errors and after hours I just cant find the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

My ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="models" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="repositories" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/messages" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>models.entities.MessagesEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

My MessagesEntity.java:

```
    package models.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usermessages", schema = "messages", catalog = "`")
public class MessagesEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "senttime")
    private Date sentTime;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Date getSentTime() {
        return sentTime;
    }

    public void setSentTime(Date time) {
        this.sentTime = time;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MessagesEntity that = (MessagesEntity) o;

        if (message != null ? !message.equals(that.message) : that.message != null)
            return false;
        if (username != null ? !username.equals(that.username) : that.username != null)
            return false;
        if (sentTime != null ? !sentTime.equals(that.sentTime) : that.sentTime!= null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = message != null ? message.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (sentTime != null ? sentTime.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projects.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>New_WebServer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>New_WebServer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <javax.javaee.version>7.0</javax.javaee.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.javaee.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-Time -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
      <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>New_WebServer</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>target</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I also created the following classes:
MessageRepositoryImpl.java

```
    import models.entities.MessagesEntity;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import repositories.MessageRepository;

@Repository
public class MessageRepositoryImpl implements MessageRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public MessagesEntity getById(long id) {
        return (MessagesEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(MessagesEntity.class, id);
    }
}
```

MessageServiceImpl.java

```
    import models.entities.MessagesEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import repositories.MessageRepository;
import services.MessageService;

@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepo;

    @Transactional
    public MessagesEntity get(long id) {
        return this.messageRepo.getById(id);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Kindly add the error stacktrace

Comment: Post the actual stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you have given catalog = "`" incorrectly in MessagesEntity . Catalogs are "namespaces" that you define on the server side of the database.